# Finding Boost compiled with CLang with CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, clang

I have compiled Boost 1.51.0 on Windows using the [rubenvb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/clang-3.1-release/)'s CLang build. I actually compiled b2 using MinGW:

```
bootstrap mingw
... compiling b2 using mingw...
```

and then I compiled the libraries with CLang:

```
b2 toolset=clang stage --stagedir=. --build-type=complete --with-regex ...
```

By the way, even if I specified `--build-type=complete` there are no DLLs in lib directory, but I read somewhere that CLang has still problem with linking on Windows so that might be the reason. Anyway static libraries are fine for me. I got these files in `%BOOST_ROOT%\lib`:

```
libboost_regex-clang31-1_51.lib
libboost_regex-clang31-d-1_51.lib
libboost_regex-clang31-mt-1_51.lib
libboost_regex-clang31-mt-d-1_51.lib
libboost_regex-clang31-mt-s-1_51.lib
libboost_regex-clang31-mt-sd-1_51.lib
libboost_regex-clang31-s-1_51.lib
libboost_regex-clang31-sd-1_51.lib
```

Now, if I compile something with CLang from command line everything works. The problem shows when I try to make CMake find Boost libraries: it simply could not find them. I tried with this CMakeFiles.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project(ccc)

# Setting/unsetting this does not change anything.
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS regex REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(ccc main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ccc
    ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY}
    )
```

Building it using MinGW (and a MinGW compiled version of Boost) it works. If I try with CLang (after having setted `CC=clang`, `CXX=clang++` and `BOOST_ROOT=C:/misc/boost/clang-1_51_0`) it does not:

```
D:\Desktop\ppp>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..\ccc
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/misc/clang/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/misc/clang/bin/clang.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/misc/clang/bin/clang++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/misc/clang/bin/clang++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at C:/misc/cmake/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1191 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.51.0

  Boost include path: C:/misc/boost/clang-1_51_0

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_regex

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "ccc" in directory D:/Desktop/ccc

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

However, if I compile manually it works again:

```
clang++ main.cpp -I%BOOST_ROOT% -L%BOOST_ROOT%\lib -llibboost_regex-clang31-1_51
...Ok, and the executable works
```

Manually setting `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` does not work either. Neither does using backslashes `\`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking inside the file "C:/misc/cmake/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake" you can find a list of all the variables related to Boost you can use. The one you need is `Boost_COMPILER` (`Boost_DETAILED_FAILURE_MSG` can also be useful to diagnose problems):

```
#   Boost_COMPILER               Set this to the compiler suffix used by Boost
#                                (e.g. "-gcc43") if FindBoost has problems finding
#                                the proper Boost installation
```

Comment: Setting `Boost_COMPILER` to `-clang31` *and* `Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME` to `TRUE` did solve the problem. Thanks.